Generated Column in use with maria db client when loading dump fails with error
│ ERROR 3105 (HY000) at line 2646: The value specified for generated column ‘concatenated_package_version’ in table ‘report’ is not allowed.                                                                                                                     
I tried to use default-mysql-client instead, same results.
At the moment I am manually deleting the last column which is declared like this:
concatenated_package_version varchar(255) as (concat("package_name", _utf8mb4':', "version"))
I read online some issues related to maria db client, but seems like switching to mysql client also ends up with the same error (I use apt-get install mariadb-client / default-mysql-client).
Any suggestions?
I load the dump using:
zcat /tmp/$filename | mysql --user="${DST_DB_USER}" --password="${DST_DB_PASS}" --host="${DST_DB_HOST}" "${DST_DB_NAME}"

My goal (what i'm trying to do): taking an sql dump, and loading it to a target db using mysql dump.

Can you attach a code or something we can see and understand?

This is a bug. The column is dumped as generated one but the value is dumped like one for regular column. The simplest solution - edit a dump removing 'generated' property, import, then alter the column.

is the create table contained in the dump or is this an already existing table?  either way, show output of show create table report; and at least one insert line that produces the error.

Looks like this bug is documented online from 2017; it wasn't properly fixed or got some interest from the code owners?
I tried switching to running with mysql community:
Running with MySQL version: mysql  Ver 8.0.38 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL), but same error.
So looks like no other way but manipulating the INSERT command in the sql dump...

The solution was indeed using the mysql client community for taking the dump and loading it. It doesn't throw any error for virtual columns.
